# ввод только чисел и работа с ними

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qtcreator

Из интернета "достал" три функции из интернета по теме : "**ввод только чисел**".

```
/* Чтение целого числа */
int getInteger()
{
    int number;
    char c; /* Временная переменная для проверки ввода */

    /* Бесконечный цикл, работающий до момента удачного считывания */
    while (1)
    {
        /* Читаем поток ввода, необходимо число завершаемое
        * символом перевода на новую строку и никак иначе
        */
        if (!scanf("%d", &number) || getchar() != '\n')
        {
            /* Очистка потока от оставшихся после чтения символов
            * для предотвращения их прочтения следующимим вызовами scanf
            */
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
        }
        else return number;

        printf("Необходимо ввести число.\nПовторите ввод: ");
    }
}

// Use setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C") for period delimeter.
double getDouble()
{
    double number;
    char c;
    while (1)
    {
        if (!scanf("%lf", &number) || getchar() != '\n')
        {
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
        }
        else return number;

        printf("Необходимо ввести число.\nПовторите ввод: ");
    }
}

long getTime()
{
    int hours, minutes;
    char c;

    while (1)
    {
        if (scanf("%d:%d", &hours, &minutes) < 2 || getchar() != '\n')
        {
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
        }
        else if (hours >= 0 && hours <= 23 && minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 59)
        {
            return hours * 60 + minutes;
        }

        printf("Необходимо время в формате HH:MM.\nПовторите ввод: ");
    }
}
```

При вводе чисел всё шикарно, вводить можно только числа.

**НО вот проблема когда я попробовал вводить числа для последующей работы с ними то получал не число, а будто бы "ссылку"**

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
    // ввести число
    double X[3]; double Y[3]; // переменные (массивы) для ввода
    memset(X,0,sizeof(X)); memset(Y,0,sizeof(Y)); // зануляем переменные(массивы)
    std::cout<< "Введите числа  векторов \n" << "------------------------ \n";
    int i = 0;  double value =0; //t int i1 =0; bool b_t =false;
    for(i =0; i<3; i++){
         printf("Введите X %d-вого вектора :", i+1);
        value=getDouble(); X[i] = value; printf(" !! %d !! ", value);
        printf("Введите Y %d-вого вектора :", i+1);
        value=getDouble(); Y[i] = value; printf(" !! %d !! ", value);
    }
//double *value1= (double *)malloc(256);
//value1=getDouble();         printf("!!!!!%d!!!!!:", value1);
    int value1 =0;
    for(i =0; i<3; i++){
         printf("Введите X %d-вого вектора :", i+1);
        value1=getInteger();  printf(" !! %d !! ", value1);
        printf("Введите Y %d-вого вектора :", i+1);
        value1=getInteger();  printf(" !! %d !! ", value1);
    }

    long value2 =0;
    for(i =0; i<3; i++){
         printf("Введите X %d-вого вектора :", i+1);
        value2=getInteger();  printf(" !! %d !! ", value2);
        printf("Введите Y %d-вого вектора :", i+1);
        value2=getInteger();  printf(" !! %d !! ", value2);
    }


for(i =0; i<=2;i++){
    printf("Вектор %d : X= %d, Y= %d \n" ,i+1, X[i], Y[i]);
}
```

Вот результат :

```
Введите числа  векторов 
------------------------ 
Введите X 1-вого вектора :1
 !! 10 !! Введите Y 1-вого вектора :2
 !! 10 !! Введите X 2-вого вектора :3
 !! 10 !! Введите Y 2-вого вектора :4
 !! 10 !! Введите X 3-вого вектора :5
 !! 10 !! Введите Y 3-вого вектора :6
 !! 10 !! Введите X 1-вого вектора :7
 !! 7 !! Введите Y 1-вого вектора :8
 !! 8 !! Введите X 2-вого вектора :9
 !! 9 !! Введите Y 2-вого вектора :11
 !! 11 !! Введите X 3-вого вектора :12
 !! 12 !! Введите Y 3-вого вектора :13
 !! 13 !! Введите X 1-вого вектора :14
 !! 14 !! Введите Y 1-вого вектора :15
 !! 15 !! Введите X 2-вого вектора :16
 !! 16 !! Введите Y 2-вого вектора :17
 !! 17 !! Введите X 3-вого вектора :18
 !! 18 !! Введите Y 3-вого вектора :19
 !! 19 !! Вектор 1 : X= 0, Y= 0 
Вектор 2 : X= 0, Y= 0 
Вектор 3 : X= 0, Y= 0
```

`getDouble()` почему то возвращает только десять , плюс к всему совершенно не кладёт в массивы `X` `Y` данные. 
Совершенно не могу понять почему так ???

---

Решил "подсмотреть" как пишут мастера (*полный справочник по СИ/ СИ плюс плюс* ) **Герберт Шилдт**.

Вот код:

```
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 printf("\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
 double v; double j;

 printf("input chislo:");
 scanf("%e", &v);

 printf("input chislo:");
 scanf("%e", &j);

 printf ("V = %d,J = %d ", v, j);

 printf("\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
//!!!!!!!!!!!!
 printf("--------------------------\n");
 int v1; int j1;

 printf("input chislo:");
 scanf("%o%x", &v1, &j1);

 printf ("V = %0,J = %x ", v1, j1);

 printf("\n------------------------\n");
//!
```

Вот вывод :

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
input chislo:21
input chislo:31
V = -502073136,J = 0 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
--------------------------
input chislo:2
3
V = %0,J = 2 
------------------------
```

Какая-то белиберда :(

Comment: Вы в массивы размера `[2]` пытаетесь пихать по 3 числа. Поведение не определено. Что вы и наблюдаете.

Comment: @AnT спасибо, исправил вопрос

Comment: printf в цикле for(i ... ) печатает  X[0], Y[0]. Это опечатка?

Comment: @user244413 исправил. ошибка осталась

Comment: 1. Вы запускаете `memset` на массив `double`. Это не очень правильно, `memset` заполняет память `unsigned char`-ами.
2. Попробуйте распечатывать все на каждом шаге: массив до ввода, каждое число после ввода и т.д.

Comment: @user244413 да что-то не так с  getDouble() . Почему-то всегда возвращает 10 ????

Comment: «Какая-то белиберда :(» Вы считываете два числа типа `double` и выводите их как целые (`%d`). Естественно будет «какая-то билиберда».

Comment: Опять же, у вас переменная `value` типа `double` вы ее выводите, как целое число: `printf(" !! %d !! ", value);`.

Comment: @eanmos исправил, НО почему получаться числа "положить" в массив ????  `Вектор 1 : X= 0, Y= 0 Вектор 2 : X= 0, Y= 0 Вектор 3 : X= 0, Y= 0 `

Comment: @timob256, все то же самое. У вас `X` — массив чисел типа `double`, а выводите вы элементы как целые: `printf("Вектор %d : X= %d, Y= %d \n" ,i+1, X[i], Y[i]);`.

Comment: @user244413, memset 0 можно делать на double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @eanmos 
Поправил :3

Ошибался с выводом в `printf` выводил `%d` надо было использовать `%f`

Вот код :

```
 // ввести число
    double X[3]; double Y[3]; // переменные (массивы) для ввода
//    memset(X,0,sizeof(X)); memset(Y,0,sizeof(Y)); // зануляем переменные(массивы)
    std::cout<< "Введите числа  векторов \n" << "------------------------ \n";
    int i = 0;  double value =0; //t int i1 =0; bool b_t =false;
    for(i =0; i<3; i++){
         printf("Введите X %d-вого вектора :", i+1);
        value=getDouble(); X[i] = value; printf(" !! %f !! ", value);
        printf("Введите Y %d-вого вектора :", i+1);
        value=getDouble(); Y[i] = value; printf(" !! %f !! ", value);
    }

    int Q[3];
    Q[0] = value; Q[1] = value; Q[2] = value;

for(i =0; i<=2;i++){
    printf("Вектор %d : X= %f, Y= %f \n" ,i+1, X[i], Y[i]);
    printf("Вектор %d : Q= %d. \n" ,i+1, Q[i]);
}
```

Вот результат:

```
Введите числа  векторов 
------------------------ 
Введите X 1-вого вектора :212
 !! 212.000000 !! Введите Y 1-вого вектора :23
 !! 23.000000 !! Введите X 2-вого вектора :32
 !! 32.000000 !! Введите Y 2-вого вектора :123
 !! 123.000000 !! Введите X 3-вого вектора :
432
 !! 432.000000 !! Введите Y 3-вого вектора :
545
 !! 545.000000 !! Вектор 1 : X= 212.000000, Y= 23.000000 
Вектор 1 : Q= 545. 
Вектор 2 : X= 32.000000, Y= 123.000000 
Вектор 2 : Q= 545. 
Вектор 3 : X= 432.000000, Y= 545.000000 
Вектор 3 : Q= 545.
```

---

*шильдовским вариантом не пользуйтесь при вводе `2123йуц231` он выведет `2123`*